# Return column with blank rows omitted

Tags: excel

I've used this forum a fair bit to find great advice but haven't needed to ask my own question yet. I am only an average excel user at best so please help me out by thoroughly explaining why certain functions are used etc in your answers. Thanks!

Ok, I have a workbook that I am using to try and keep track of stock of a large number of products. On one sheet I have all the product codes that exist listed down the A column, and all the colours they can come in listed across the top row (I will draw an example).

On another sheet I have made it possible with vlookup, if, and iferror functions to look up how much stock I have of any single product number either in all the colours available, or just a particular colour of my choice.

Now what I want to be able to do is just select a colour and have excel generate a list showing only the product codes of what is in stock in that colour, and how many there are. I've been looking around a bit and read a little about array formulas, but I don't think that is what I am looking for?

Example: I wanted to upload a picture, but I can't yet because I am a new member. I don't know how to draw a table in here...

I don't want the list to display any codes that there are 0 stock of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there any many ways to do this. My first thought would be a Filters or a Pivot Table. They are both great when you want to select part of your data based on a criteria (e.g. a colour).

PivotTables can be tricky and will only work if the data is set out in a specific way.

I'd need to see some screenshots or the workbook to really help you out. I'll PM you my email and if noone helps, send it over and I'll check it out.

EDIT: Can't figure out how to PM you :P

Maybe upload the workbook or an example somewhere?

Lucas

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried including pictures but I need 10 rep to do so - lame! Ok, hopefully you can check out these pictures:

This first one is how the data is set out.
[url=http://postimg.org/image/o6ap4zlal/][img]http://s30.postimg.org/o6ap4zlal/Example_1.jpg[/img][/url]

And this second one is how I want the data displayed when it is filtered etc.
[url=http://postimg.org/image/64rk76r9p/][img]http://s30.postimg.org/64rk76r9p/Example_2.jpg[/img][/url]

If this isn't enough for you to create a small mock DB to test things then I'll try and figure out a way to get the work book to you.

Comment: I'll have to check back in a bit later mate. After work tonight perhaps ;)

Comment: Thanks mate. Those links are broken, I must have used the wrong code to insert them. If you just copy the url out from the start of them then they work.

Comment: Ok I've made some headway, I've managed to generate the desired list with nested IF commands and VLOOKUP. And then I can apply a filter to the list to omit the rows with a '0' stock count. This however requires you to refresh the filter each time you update the colour that you are searching for. I want to be able to send you my workbook so you can look over it. Can you recommend somewhere I can upload it for you? Or if you figure out how to PM on here I can email it to you. Cheers.